# how can I get data from a table that is liked to a table that is liked to another one it self?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, django-models

I have three tables,result, course and study, they are like follows

```
class Study(models.Model):
    id_study = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    study_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    number_of_years = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Course(models.Model):
    id_course = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    credits = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    teacher_id_teacher = models.ForeignKey('Teacher', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='teacher_id_teacher')
    study_id_study = models.ForeignKey('Study', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='study_id_study')

class Exam(models.Model):
    id_exam = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    room = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    resit = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    course_id_course = models.ForeignKey(Course, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='course_id_course')


class Result(models.Model):
    id_result = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    grade = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    exam_id_exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='exam_id_exam')
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    student_id_student = models.ForeignKey('Student', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='student_id_student')
    passed = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get a result object depending on the study_id I give

Result depends on Exam, Exam depends on Course and Course depends on study

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the `Result` -> `Course` relationship?

Comment: I think you're confusing "depends on" with "is a child of". A chapter is a child of a book. Given a book you can't get a unique chapter. Given a chapter you have a unique book that it is a part of. The upshot is that I think your result isn't uniquely determined. For a study object, you will get a set of courses. Namely, study.course_set.all()

Comment: @IainShelvington I have just corrected my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow relationships in queries by using the double underscore notation

```
Result.objects.filter(
    exam_id_exam__course_id_course__study_id_study__id=study_id
)
```

For what it's worth: you have an odd naming convention for your foreign keys, usually a foreign key to a model named `Exam` would be named `exam`, you are already setting `db_column` for each foreign key so you don't need to name them this way. If you changed their names to be the model name lowercase it would look like this which is probably more readable

```
Result.objects.filter(exam__course__study__id=study_id)
```

Comment: thank you so much, exactly what I needed,is there a query for that in sql as well ;)

Comment: Printing `queryset.query` will output the resulting SQL -> `print(Result.objects.filter(exam_id_exam__course_id_course__study_id_study__id=study_id).query)`